# Is there a way for gcc to disable specific warning

Tags: gcc, warnings

I define a PRINTF MACRO as below shown:

```
#if(PRINTF_VERSION & PRINTF_DISABLE)
    #define CYPRINTF
#else
    #define CYPRINTF    printf
#endif
```

But when print is disabled, I got below warning:

```
warning: statement with no effect
```

I have tried below solution, it works well with GCC compiler, but can't work with compiler which doesn't support variadic MACRO.

```
#if(PRINTF_VERSION & PRINTF_DISABLE)
    #define CYPRINTF(format, ...)
#else
    #define CYPRINTF    printf
#endif
```

How can I change the non-logging macro such that no warning is issued?

Notes:

1. I don't want to add compiling flag `-Wunused-value`.
2. I don't want to use variadic MACRO.
3. When printf is disabled, all the code should be removed to avoid affecting system performance.

Comment: Since GCC supports variadic macros, you can avoid the warning with GCC easily.  Which other compiler produces the warning you're worried about — which other compiler that does not support variadic macros, that is?  (I can guess, but you should state which.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the gcc's [diagnostic pragmas.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.3/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) and [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple: don't use macros.

```
#if(PRINTF_VERSION & PRINTF_DISABLE)
int CYPRINTF(const char*, ...)
{ return 0; }
#else
#include <cstdarg>
int CYPRINTF(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int ret = vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
#endif
```

You can also instruct GCC to type-check the format string by using the "format" __attribute__ (see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: but, this will affect the system performance, especially for the embedded system.

Comment: Are you sure it will affect performance?  You might be surprised at how good at optimization GCC is.

Comment: @Vincent I/O is slow. Even if the function doesn't get inlined, the cost of a function call is nothing compared to doing the I/O with (v)printf(). In the case where the empty function is picked, the compiler will not generate a function call at all, since it can easily deduct in this case that the function does nothing. And I highly doubt that you're doing calls to CYPRINTF in a tight loop anyway. Do you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my application is targeted at consumer applications, my MCU has only 8KB flash and 1KB RAM; so I don't want any unused code in release version @Nikos C. And I don't want the dependency on the compiler optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is like really old, but try this:

```
#if(PRINTF_VERSION & PRINTF_DISABLE)
  #define CYPRINTF    (void)
#else
  #define CYPRINTF    printf
#endif
```

The void cast should tell the compiler that this statement has no value. I have not tested it, but have tried similar stuff in the past. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option, I've used today. @Fëamarto answer is good, but does not work for me, as I use a complex printing with a multi-level wrapping of printing macros.

But lambdas does a magic:

```
#if(PRINTF_VERSION & PRINTF_DISABLE)
    #define CYPRINTF [](){return 0;}()
#else
    #define CYPRINTF    printf
#endif
```